# Enterprise geodatabase maintenance Esri vs. SQL Server (rebuild index and update statistics)

Tags: sql, enterprise-geodatabase, sql-server, maintenance

I'm looking at two geodatabase maintenance practices and seeing if they need to be updated/refined, and I'm noticing that these can be accomplished via ESRI tools or directly via SQL / within SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS):

A. Update database statistics:

- ESRI: AnalyzeDatasets_management
- SSMS: Auto Update Statistics = TRUE in Database Properties

B. Rebuild indexes on system tables:

- ESRI: RebuildIndexes_management
- SSMS: DROP INDEX/CREATE SPATIAL INDEX commands

In what scenarios would someone use the SSMS/SQL approach instead of relying on the ESRI commands?

Comment: As per the [Tour] there should be only one question asked per question.

Comment: Provided you run the same exact SQL directives, this purely a matter of preference.

Comment: Thank you @Vince! How do I know what SQL directive the ESRI command is generating?